# Confusion with CruseControl.NET sourcecontrol exclusionFilters patterns

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

we are using CruiseControl.NET for our build process and in ccnet.config, I want to exclude changes to a particular directory and it's children from triggering that project's build, but what I've tried keeps triggering the project's build.

**Example repo**

- trunk/

  - foo/

    - index.html
  - ignoreme/

    - index.html
  - bar/
- branches/
- tags/

**Example ccnet.config**

```
<sourcecontrol type="filtered">
    <sourceControlProvider type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>$(RootUrl)/trunk</trunkUrl>
        <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
    </sourceControlProvider>
    <exclusionFilters>
        <pathFilter>
            <pattern>/ignoreme/**</pattern>
        </pathFilter>
    </exclusionFilters>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Committing anything into the ignoreme directory should not trigger this project. What should the pattern be (existing: `/ignoreme/**`)?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path instead of relative for the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the working pattern:

```
/trunk/ignoreme/**/*.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but here's a simple alternative -
Use [Interval trigger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Interval+Trigger) with global [SVN](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Subversion+Source+Control+Block) update, and then use [FileSystem trigger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Filesystem+Source+Control+Block) in other projects, referencing needed folders only.

HTH